# Continue bubbling up inside a loop in PHP

Tags: php, loops, continue

I adapted a web script I wrote to fit my needs for some data I need to retrieve from a server. I run this script from a terminal, so error messages are useful information.

The main part of the code is a loop inside a loop, and in that loop I call a function. In this function there's a call to a database. If there is a problem with connecting to the database, I can catch that error with a simple `try {} catch(){}`, but how should I structure my code so that I can just *skip* this iteration and move to the next item in the loop? In other words, do a `continue` only from within a function.

Below is how I would do it, but I am not sure this is the correct way.

```
foreach ($flavours as $icecream) {
  foreach ($sauces as $sauce) {
    $amount = dessertServings($icecream, $sauce);
    if ($amount != null) {
      // Some other functions like orderDessert, makePricingList and so on
      fwrite(STDOUT, "$amount servings of $icecream with $sauce remaining!\n");
    }
  }
}

dessertServings($icecream, $sauce) {
  try {
    $dbConnection = new Connection("user", "password", "db$icecream$sauce");
    $amountOfServings = $dbConnection->query($icecream, $sauce);
    return $amountOfServings;
  }
  // E.g database connection could not be made
  catch(Exception $e) {
    fwrite(STDERR, $e->getMessage() . "\n");
    return;
  }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

To make things harder, **what if the function doesn't actually return anything** and thus isn't assigning a value to a variable? How should you deal with that?

```
foreach ($flavours as $icecream) {
  foreach ($sauces as $sauce) {
    prepareDessert($icecream, $sauce);
    // Other functions, most importantly: eatDessert($dessert)
  }
}

prepareDessert($icecream, $sauce) {
  try {
    $dbConnection = new Connection("user", "password", "db$icecream$sauce");
    $dbConnection->query($icecream, $sauce)->do("prepare");
  }
  // E.g database connection could not be made
  catch(Exception $e) {
    fwrite(STDERR, $e->getMessage() . "\n");
  }
}
```

In such a case, how do I make sure that when the `try` fails, the block in the loop never reaches the *other functions*, we can't eat an ice cream that wasn't prepared in the first place!

Would I use an empty variable that simply returns true on success and false and fail, and execute the following code in the main block only on true? Or is there a better convention for this in PHP?

Comment: Only initiate one database connection, before you even start looping. Use this one connection throughout. It doesn't make sense to create a new connection using the same credentials for each iteration, when you can simply maintain your initial one (providing it's successful).

Comment: Yeah, create your connection, if it succeeds then run your loop, if it fails then display your error.

Comment: @George Improved the example.

Comment: First, you need to have your individual functions make a contract so that everyone knows what to expect when they use them. So, 1) They always return a value but it may be an error. i.e. Always return an array with a status code?  2) They always throw an exception on an error but return a useful value in all other cases. So, once you know what the contract is then writing the code is possible?

Comment: @RyanVincent I don't really see why one does not allow the other. If I throw an exception I can (in that catch block) still return a value, right? And I need the following item in the loop run as well, without finish the current iteration. So I cannot simply exit.

Comment: Correct, the issue isn't what you do with the exception - that is up to you.  It is just that everyone knows what will happen when that  function executes. i.e .it either *always*  returns a useful value or it throws the  error exception sometimes. If you catch the exception and have it return a value then - it always returns a useful value by defintion.

Comment: The real point is that your: _'what if the function doesn't actually return anything'_ can never happen or be allowed to happen. Those situations  we know as _bugs_ as the program is no longer deterministic.

Comment: @RyanVincent I know it's like that in Java, which will actually throw a compilation error, but I never heard it was required in PHP for a function to return something.

Comment: The PHP function  is not required to return anything - PHP will not complain - but how does the calling program know what to do? Should there been an exception? Should there be a valid value? This is about the program calling the function. Should it report an error or continue to process a valid value it never got?

Comment: Remember, we are not allowed to have code that checks whether the contract is correct. We agreed - we call the function: it returns a valid result always. Or it returns a valid result OR throws an exception. Anything else is a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how should I structure my code so that I can just skip this iteration and move to the next item in the loop

**The first rule of exception handling: do not do exception handling.** Allow it to bubble up and catch it when you need it (in your case, in your loop).

You can also re-throw an exception in your catch, if you want to do some processing within the function (like print to STDERR), but let it bubble up!

The other more traditional method is to have your function return some kind of error code -  the most basic being "true" on success, "false" or "null" on failure like in your first example. I don't see anything wrong with that.

> To make things harder, what if the function doesn't actually return anything and thus isn't assigning a value to a variable? How should you deal with that?

Throw exceptions, that's their job!

> how do I make sure that when the try fails, the block in the loop never reaches the other functions

Don't try/catch within the function or re-throw an exception from within your "catch".

> Would I use an empty variable that simply returns true on success and false and fail, and execute the following code in the main block only on true? Or is there a better convention for this in PHP?

Yes there is a better convention : throw exceptions.